# How can I change the url for a project in GitLab?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project in Gitlab that is available over HTTP/SSH:

```
git@192.168.1.10:MyGroup/MyProject.git
```

I want to change that using another IP, i.e.:

```
git@192.168.1.20:MyGroup/MyProject.git
```

Where or how can I change that?

Comment: Do you mean you've moved the repo to a new server (with new IP address) and want to know how to update clones to find it at this new location? Or do you mean you want to know what to do with the repo, so that this new URL would find it? Or something else?

Answer (score 21):

You can use below command to set new URL for your repository.

```
git remote set-url origin git://git@192.168.1.20:MyGroup/MyProject.git
```

Comment: Should be the correct answer! ✅ Also to see that it took effect: `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all repositories remotes inside the file `.git/config`. You can edit it by hand or use command `git remote`.

Answer (score 2):

once You set url don't forget to check

```
git remote set-url origin git://git@192.168.1.20:MyGroup/MyProject.git
```

to check url properly set or not use below command

```
git remote show origin
```

or

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```