# changing the git repository url which has been imported to my gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

I installed a self-managed instance of gitlab-ce and imported a repository like `http://my.git.domain/first-repo.git` url to my project through **Create a new project > Import project from > Repo by URL**. after some work, now I want to change the source of my project so that I want to import source code from another git url such as `http://my.git.domain/second-repo.git` .
can anyone tell me:

1- is it basically possible to do that (change source of a repository in gitlab)?

2- if yes, how do I so?

I read similar solution here [How can I change the url for a project in GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390210/how-can-i-change-the-url-for-a-project-in-gitlab) but I did not understand what should I do with graphical admin menus in gitlab or where I'm supposed to insert git commands?

Comment: Are you using command-line Git, or are you using some sort of GUI? If you are using a GUI, remove the tag [tag:git] and insert instead the tag for that GUI.

Comment: to @torek : I am using gitlab interface GUI, not git cli. but my question is about git repository management part of gitlab, so I think it's better to tag it by git.

Comment: The repository management done *by* that GUI is specific *to* that GUI. You would use different techniques for a different GUI. Note that you're getting command-line answers; that's because you used the command-line tag.

Answer (score 1):

To change Remote repository ,Use This Command

`$ git remote set-url origin http://my.git.domain/second-repo.git`

This command will change Remote repo .

Comment: I am dealing with GUI gitlab. give me a hand to know where should I set your suggested command in git?

Comment: Open your Terminal or Command prompt.Navigate to your git project Folder (if project is not available in local ,Clone your repo ).And paste the suggested Command. (Make sure Git is installed in your computer).

Comment: I got your directions help  me to change my repository content with new source codes in my local computer and then I push new sorce code into my project's git repo in gitlab. I got that. but I want to know also what was my source git url when I created a project in gitlab. I found a manual in [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) which explains how to sync my gitlab repository with an external remote repo . but this is not my answer.